# get 415 Unsupported Media Type when testing my .Net Web API using postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

The below code is my `UploadImagea` action in my controller.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("UploadImage")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("[action]")]
        public async Task<string> UploadImage( IFormFile file, string folder, int SchoolId, byte EnvironmentType)
        {
            _galleryService.InvokeAzureSettings(SchoolId, EnvironmentType);
            try
            {
                var res = await ((GalleryService)_galleryService).UploadImage(folder, file);
                return res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

The below screenshots is from my postman, the Content-Type I'm testing is `multipart/form-data` . All other actions are working fine. I don't know why I get 415 error code, how to solve it?
[image: sc1]
[image: sc2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a model to hold the desired form data

```
public class Model {
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    public string folder { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public byte EnvironmentType { get; set; }
}
```

Update the action to expect the data from a form using the appropriate attribute

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("UploadImage")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<string> UploadImage([FromForm] Model model) {

    _galleryService.InvokeAzureSettings(model.SchoolId, model.EnvironmentType);
    try {
        var res = await ((GalleryService)_galleryService).UploadImage(model.folder, model.file);
        return res;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `[FromForm]` attribute to my method argument works for me.

Answer (score 1):

No need to define any file in body just check if the client side is sending file in body by using HttpRequest from IHttpContextAccessor.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult UploadDocument()
    {

        var httpRequest = context.HttpContext.Request;
        List<IFormFile> lstFiles = new List<IFormFile>();
        foreach (var files in httpRequest.Form.Files)
        {
            lstFiles.Add(files);
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```